# Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image not found SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-emulator, autoplay, android-automotive

I am trying to start Automotive emulator reading this article https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing

To install the generic system image:
In Android Studio, select Tools > SDK Manager.
Click the SDK Platforms tab.
Click Show Package Details.
Under Android 9.0 (Pie), select Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image.
Click Apply, then click OK.

but unfortunately couldn't find  Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image

[image]

any idea why Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image is not available

Answer (score 3):

[image: Android Studio SDK Manager]

The automotive feature is added from the canary version. Try 3.5 or later versions, this is a snippet from 4.0 version

Comment: I have studio 4.0 but not seeing this option. Could you show your update sites screen?

Comment: Are you saying that even in AS 4+ you still need to be using the Canary version?

Comment: @Fracdroid, user2199860, I moved to another project, so due to space constraints, I uninstalled studio from my PC but my understanding is that we need to select the canary channel to receive updates wrt automotive which can be selected under the System Settings -> Updates (Automatically check updates for Canary Channel)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as I was on Stable Channel Updates.
Tried @Kishore P suggestion and switched to Canary Channel, and there it was - Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image.

Steps -
Ctrl+Shift+A open the Find Action search box
Search System Settings
System Settings > Updates
SDK Manager > SDK Platforms > Check Show Package Details box
Now you can find Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image under Android 9.0 (Pie)
Go ahead and install.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Automative System Images are only available to download for Android Studio Previews. Once downloaded, you can use them in Android Studio Stable.

Solution:

- Download the Android Studio Preview if you don't already have it.
- Download the desired system image from SDK manager in AS Preview.
- Switch to the AS Stable to create your emulator with the system image you downloaded.